# Chrome _ = Safari 4

Tags: browser-support

What version of Chrome is equivalent to Safari 4?

If anyone knows the same about Safari 3 and 5 as well, that'd be helpful.

Comment: @muntoo Tried, and I didn't find anything. That's why I came here.

Comment: Equal in what sense? They're definitely not the same browser, they just share a common backend (which is patched differently).

Comment: Lol, I was making a (really terrible) joke about a hypothetical browser named "Google Safari". (As in "Google Chrome".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these two articles to match the webkit versions:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history

e.g. Safari 4 featured Webkit 530-533, matching Chrome versions 2-5.

Comment: So the latest version of Safari 4 would be equivalent to Chrome 5. Thanks. :)

Comment: At least the rendering should be about the same, but they have different javascript engines, so dynamic contents might not behave exactly the same.